# AJAX sort by query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am looking to add a 'sort by' option...
when the page first loads its shows all the content throw this function:

```
function latest($n) {
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "artlibr1_default", "azerty123", "artlibr1_01");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $n, 1";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 return $list['path'];
}
```

But if i want to be more precise in the search i can can, for example, only want to show elements where type="painting".

So for that i would need to change my function's sql statement to something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE type="painting" ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $n, 1";
```

I imagine i need to do an AJAX but realy don't see how to get this done :/ ( i have done simple AJAX calls before) If you guys could help me out, it would be great !

Comment: What makes You think You need ajax for that? You don't need javascript at all, probably. Then the page will reload in between.

Comment: @entio I think i need AJAX because the page loads up first of all with all elements; it is only after the user chooses to sort by that the page needs to change again, the only way as far as i know to change a page once it is loaded is AJAX.

Comment: @Jackymamouth, Then go with the AJAX..What stops you ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't see how to proceed :/ i have done ajax but it was only for like button system . I can't relate on how to do this , i have looked around a bit but can't see in what direction i should go or do this . if you could just give the guidlines it would be great

Comment: Send values to be considered over PHP as `data` in AJAX config..and then return the JSON and iterate it over client side...

Comment: @RayonDabre  I can Ajax on same page and do an if statement ?: if $POST['parameterajax1'] exist then query with needed sql statement otherwise use default sql statement

Answer (score 1):

You could do an ajax request and then update the data on your page. However, depending how much data you are displaying/filtering you may find the quickest and most eloquent solution is to use a js filter plugin such as:

Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
or
TinySort: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

They will keep the existing data in the DOM, but show/hide what the user sees. That means it will be very quick as you're not doing additional calls.

Comment: Interesting solution i didn't consider to use a plugin;
i already have an ajax request soo that more of the content loads when arriving at the bottom of screen so i shouldn't have too many elements to Sort at once but the plugin does have same nice effects with it